# PostgreSQL query suddenly very slow after new column addition

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.6, rails

I have a query that's performing terribly after adding a new column. Here's the slow version:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM activities
INNER JOIN "users" ON "users"."id" = "activities"."user_id" AND "users"."api_user_for" IS NULL
WHERE "activities"."department_id" = 123456789
AND "users"."api_user_for" IS NULL
```

The new column is the `api_user_for` column. It's a nullable string type. The SQL itself is generated from Ruby on Rails. We've added a "default scope", and that's why the `api_user_for` seems to appear twice in the query (on the join and in the where clause).

If I remove *either one* of those `api_user_for` checks, the query returns to its former speed. By including them both, however, the query moves from taking less than 100ms to taking close to 10 seconds.

I've compared the query plans using PEV, and here's the fast and slow queries compared:

[image: fast query]
[image: slow query]

The "fast query" in this case is the same query with one of the (unnecessarily duplicated) `api_user_for` checks removed. For example, both of these queries are fast:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM activities
INNER JOIN "users" ON "users"."id" = "activities"."user_id"
WHERE "activities"."department_id" = 123456789
AND "users"."api_user_for" IS NULL
```

and

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM activities
INNER JOIN "users" ON "users"."id" = "activities"."user_id" AND "users"."api_user_for" IS NULL
WHERE "activities"."department_id" = 123456789
```

Obviously there's a huge disparity in the number of loops performed, but why are these loops taking place? The scan seems otherwise very similar.

I would love some insight into what could be going on as this fairly innocuous query is now bringing performance to its knees!

Postgres Version: 9.6.8

Answer (score 2):

It looks like we needed to run `ANALYZE users`!

I had run `ANALYZE activities`, but that wasn't the problematic table. I guess the query planner thought that the `api_user_for` column would be instructive to help it remove rows, but the column was almost entirely filled with `NULL` values, so it would not have helped much at all.

Obviously running a simple `ANALYZE` would also have solved the problem.